# Play mp3/audio on Google Drive preview at specific time

Tags: audio, google-drive-api, drive

I have an audio file (e.g. mp3) located on Google Drive and accessible at a direct url that looks like `https://drive.google.com/file/d/audio_file_id/view` where there is a small sliding bar timeline scrubber and play/pause button that let the user hear the audio (and supposedly control the location in the file, but this feature is not working for me on Chrome on mac…; advice on this appreciated).

I would like to start the playback at a specific time.  How can this be one? Is there a way to do it like one can do with video files hosted on Google Drive by adding a parameter like `t=15s` to the video url, like in YouTube?

Comment: try my answer and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Drive API doesn't have the [seekTo](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#seekTo) method in Youtube API but you can add the t=123s at the end of the video url and it will work just like it.

sample:

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz6447wI7cGV12546VBmQ2M/view?t=651s
```